# Can we get the creator of the video who has uploaded in the channel using Youtube data api?

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to fetch the data from Youtube and planning to generate the reports based on metrics.

So, Is there any possibility to get the creator name of the video who has uploaded in the channel ?

Can anyone please suggest me regarding the same ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to retrieve your videos:

```
 curl https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search\?part\=snippet\&channelId\=INPUTCHANNELID\&maxResults\=10\&order\=date\&type\=video\&key\=YOURAPIKEY
```

from here you can do:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos\?part\=statistics\&id\=VIDEOID\&key\=YOURAPIKEY
```

but if you want daily metrics, you're likely going to need to use oauth2